# jQuery .remove() option using :contains()

Tags: jquery

At the bottom of the page is a line "Step 2" that opens an accordion tab. On the first section of the interface is a 2nd Drop down that reads Select Servive.

Im trying to use :contains() and .remove() to remove the options that contain the word Phone in the text. Here's my code, but it doesn't seem to  work. My error reads that Im missing a closing ) but I cant see where.

```
<select class="ab-formElement ab-select-mobile ab-select-service">
   <option value="">Select service</option>
   <option value="1">Early Pregnancy Scan</option>
   <option value="2">2D Sexing / Gender Scan</option>
   <option value="18">Phone Booking Only &gt; Bundle of Joy</option>     
</select>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$=jQuery;
var option = jQuery('select.ab-select-service option:contains('Phone')');
$(option).remove();
});
```

UPDATE:
Ive noticed something else. 
Anything i try to do to any of the elements within this plugin seem to not work. Theres a difference in the syntax on my jQuery and the code in the scripts file.

https://jsfiddle.net/7oh7k47m/

Comment: What's the relevant HTML? Bearing in mind this is irrelevant to the problem, given the typo [identified by meagar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32854012/82548)); but it's easier in most cases to offer help when a question contains a "[MCVE]."

Comment: Is the code you posted here the exact same as your code? You're using `'` to open your string but also to specify `'Phone'` and that's likely why you're getting the error.

Comment: Exactly the same, none of your solutions seem to be working. I tried to add the URL to the question but it was removed.

Comment: Do you get any error messages when you try to access elements affected by the plugin?

Comment: nope. although i am going about it a slightly differnt way. trying now to use the actual HTML template and put the script directly into there. Which is working however, I added a small function  jQuery('select.ab-select-service option').remove() which weirdly enough only removed the first option. The rest remain.

Answer (score 1):

You're nesting `'` inside `'`, prematurely terminating your string. You need to escape your nested `'` with `\'`.

```
var option = jQuery('select.ab-select-service option:contains(\'Phone\')');
```

Comment: Exactly the same, none of your solutions seem to be working. I tried to add the URL to the question but it was removed.

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes around `Phone` are closing the selector string.

Try changing your quotes around phone into double quotes ("Phone"):

`var option = jQuery('select.ab-select-service option:contains("Phone")');`

or escaping the single quote with a backslash:

`var option = jQuery('select.ab-select-service option:contains(\'Phone\')');`

According to the jQuery website, you can also remove the quotes altogether:

> As with attribute value selectors, text inside the parentheses of :contains() can be written as a bare word or surrounded by quotation marks. The text must have matching case to be selected.

https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: Exactly the same, none of your solutions seem to be working. I tried to add the web address to the question but it was removed.

Comment: @AlexKnopp - It seems to be working here: http://jsfiddle.net/jnrrczgy/ Does that match your example?

Comment: Ditto i just tested the same. Is there anyway I can post the link to my site to see if anyone has any further input on why this script might not be working?

Comment: @AlexKnopp I just posted a fiddle link. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @NKD but Im still not able to get this working on my site. Im wondering if my scripts are loading in the correct order. Tried window.load but still doesnt work.

Comment: @AlexKnopp - I just executed the code on your site locally using developer tools and it worked fine. Try replacing your code with a console.log() or alert() to check it is invoked correctly.

Comment: @AlexKnopp May I ask what is not working? Are you still getting the same error complaining about missing a closing ) ?

Comment: @AlexKnopp - You could also try replacing `$(option).remove();` with `jQuery(option).remove();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var option = jQuery('select.ab-select-service option:contains(\'Phone\')');
```

My answer is pretty much similar. The only difference here is that I have a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/enge6saa/